# Filter data frames stored in list based on row numbers

Tags: r, list, loops

I have following problem.
I am storing multiple data frames in a list environment. I wrote a loop that is supposed to iterate through the data frames in the list and deletes the too short ones. But somehow, deleting data frames from the list is not successful.

```
datalist # a list containing data frames

for (i in 1:length(datalist)) {
  datset <- datalist[i]
  if (nrow(datset) < 25) {
    sub_name <- names(datset)
    datalist <- datalist[-sub_name]
  }
}
```

I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the follwing:

```
dataSetRowCounts <- sapply(datalist,NROW)
datalist[dataSetRowCounts < 25] <- NULL
datalist
```

First, get the number of rows for every `data.frame` in the list. Second, delete the listelements with less than 25 rows by setting them to `NULL`

Comment: Works just perfect. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) >= 25, datalist)
```

or `subset`

```
subset(datalist, sapply(datalist, nrow) >= 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `keep`

```
library(purrr)
keep(data_list, ~ nrow(.x) >= 25)
```